# How to query the existence of a key in PostgreSQL 9.5 JSONB column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, operators, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 database table with a JSONB column called attrs. I want to check the existence of a particular key within that attires column. I think I can use the ? operator, but I don't understand the syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM cereal WHERE attrs ? 'lbs';
```

This returns, "The number of minded parameters < the number of parameter markers."

```
SELECT * FROM cereal WHERE attrs ? | ARRAY['lbs'];
```

This returns, "The number of minded parameters < the number of parameter markers."

How do I query the existence of a key in a JSONB column?

Comment: How are you running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually spot on with your first query.

The `?` operator does have the limitation that it only examines the top-level keys of the `jsonb` value. So it is likely that the key you are looking for is buried somewhere deeper in your JSON document. You can use a number of `jsonb` operators or processing functions to drill down to where the key is supposed to be located and then do the test: `->`, `#>`, `jsonb_each()` or `jsonb_array_elements()`, among others. So you use any of these and run the `?` operator over the result, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM cereal
WHERE (attrs -> 'weight') ? 'lbs';
```

...for a JSON document like:

```
{"ingredients": {...}, "weight": {"lbs": 4, "kg": 1.8}, ...}
```

Without any knowledge of the structure of your JSON document you won't get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a postgresql error. Your query is fine. The error is your that whatever you're using to run that query is confusing `?` for a parameter placeholder, you must fix the way you're trying to run the query and you didn't provide enough information to give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will file a bug on psequel, which is what I was using to run the query.